# Android Studio : dupliacate class found error

Tags: java, android, duplicates

I'm learning Android at the moment.
I made 2 layout file first and 2 java file.
I connect them but I got error
checkDebugDuplicateClasses
dupliacate class found

I got just 2 files I can't find any duplicate classes

```
package com.example.fitcord;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class Activity_main extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onClick(View view){
        startActivity(new Intent("com.example.fitcord.Activity_setting"));
    }

}
```

```
package com.example.fitcord;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class Activity_setting extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_setting);
    }
}
```

These are my 2 java file's code

Is it problem of layout?
or What should I do?

Comment: Post full logcat where the error occur

Comment: There was no line or something to see where the error occur in my files, but I found some case who had same problem as me.  It's because of the version of Library.... but I still don't know why the message that I got said duplicate classes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this way to start new activity:

`startActivity(new Intent(Activity_main.this, Activity_setting.class));`

Comment: If Rohit fix works mark as answer @Beginner-K it may confuse new people who face the same problem.